# Can I do a "test run" with rsnapshot?

Tags: backup, rsnapshot

I occasionally make changes to my `rsnapshot.conf` and I'm wondering if there's any way I can do a test run that is sync-ed to a location other than the normal flow... something that's not an `interval`. Is this possible? how?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*I don't have an `rsnapshot` setup to test this on. Be careful.*

Personally, I think that the best thing to do is to carefully evaluate the output of `rsnapshot -t interval`. However if you want to actually move files, one way to do it might be to create an alternate config file that is identical to your real config file but with a different `snapshot_root` such as:

```
snapshot_root   /test/backup/path
```

And then you can run your test using

```
rsnapshot -c rsnapshot.test.conf interval0
```

where `interval0` is your lowest order interval.

Answer (score 7):

- Testing configuration `sudo rsnapshot configtest` should get you a `Syntax ok`
- Dry testing will be `sudo rsnapshot -t daily`
- Complete test will be `sudo rsnapshot daily`

You can do the same with either hourly|weekly|monthly

Comment: Worked for me. However the syntax was ok (from a rsnapshot point of view) but not from a rsync point of view, so I add to try `rsnapshot -t sync` (sync is where the actual work happen)